# Ignore CodeIgniter i18n routes if specific URL is called

Tags: codeigniter

I'm builiding a multi-language site on CodeIgniter and I am using routes to force the language to be in the URL, like this:

```
// URI like '/en/about' -> use controller 'about'
$route['^(en|de|fr|nl)/(.+)$'] = "$2";

// '/en', '/de', '/fr' and '/nl' URIs -> use default controller
$route['^(en|de|fr|nl)$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

With this, if you go to `mydomain.com/auth/login` you are redirected to `mydomain.com/en/auth/login` but I want to avoid this only on specific URL called. Like I always want the language to be in the URL except when you call `mydomain.com/get/123`, it should remain as it.

I tried to add this before the previous routes, unsuccessfully:

```
$route['get/(:num)'] = "get/$1";
```

Thank you for your help, routes are getting me lost.

Comment: did you try to add needed to avoid URLs to omit this in first regexp, then define route for that below ?

Comment: I don't understand your question?

Comment: Sorry. why does it redirect you to %/en/% ? is it defined in .htaccess?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisG.B.  do you want to route or to disable i18 for a specific url?

Comment: @okok Route or disable. I can manually charge language after for those cases.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it could help.

```
$default_controller = "webpages";
$language_alias = array('gr','fr');
$controller_exceptions = array('admin','forums');

$route['default_controller'] = $default_controller;
$route["^(".implode('|', $language_alias).")/(".implode('|', $controller_exceptions).")(.*)"] = '$2';
$route["^(".implode('|', $language_alias).")?/(.*)"] = $default_controller.'/$2';
$route["^((?!\b".implode('\b|\b', $controller_exceptions)."\b).*)$"] = $default_controller.'/$1';
foreach($language_alias as $language)
    $route[$language] = $default_controller.'/index';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

The only thing that you will actually care to change is the first three lines of code:

```
$default_controller = "webpages";
$language_alias = array('gr','fr');
$controller_exceptions = array('admin','forums');
```

The $language_alias is the language element that you want to add if you have a multilingual website for example:

- http://mycustomproject.com/blog
- http://mycustomproject.com/gr/blog
- http://mycustomproject.com/fr/blog

And of course the http://mycustomproject.com/gr and http://mycustomproject.com/fr are routing to the index of your basic Controller.

The $controller_exceptions are the controllers that will NOT follow this routing structure. For example:

- http://mycustomproject.com/admin/
- http://mycustomproject.com/forums/

from [here](http://www.web-and-development.com/codeigniter-minimize-url-and-remove-index-php/)

Answer (score 0):

How about just using the newer version of the library which provides built-in $special array for non-localized areas.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the newer Library which includes specials URI's for creating non-localized areas. More info can be found here: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/CodeIgniter-2.1-internationalization-i18n

Comment: link only answers are frowned upon here.  maybe you should summarize what's at the link.

Answer (score 0):

Just for information, forcing the redirection from `mydomain.com/auth/login` to `mydomain.com/en/auth/login` is not something related to the routes files, it's the file `MY_Lang.php` file provided with the library which redirects the user to the default language.